# Error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'card.image') React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Theres a screen where I show the cards, firstly it shows all the cards without filter and I'm trying to create his functionality of filter but shows this error, HELP ME PLS.[image: ERROR UNDEFINED IS NOT AN OBJECT(evaluating 'card.image')] The code is this:

```
const [preferenceSelected, setPreferenceSelected] = useState("");
  const [list, setList] = useState(data);
  
  useEffect(() =>{
    if(preferenceSelected === ''){
      setList(data);
    }else{
      setList(
        data.filter(item => {
          if(item.categoria === preferenceSelected){
            console.log(list);
            return true;
          }else{
            return false;
          }
        })
        )
    }
  }), [preferenceSelected];
```

```
<View style={styles.EventCards}>  
       <Swiper
          cards={list}
          renderCard={(card) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity  style={styles.card} onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate('EventProfile', {
                  id: card.id,
                  nome: card.nome,
                  categoria: card.categoria,
                  image: card.image,
                  avaliacao: card.avaliacao,

                });
              }} >
                
                <Image source={{uri:card.image}} style={styles.cardImg}  />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }}
          stackSize={4}
          stackSeparation={10}
          disableBottomSwipe
          disableTopSwipe
          verticalSwipe={false}
          backgroundColor={"transparent"}
          keyExtractor={card => card.id}
        
        ></Swiper>
```

I tried to create his filter method but it always showed an error. And I'm using his dependency to utilize animated card.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself getting this error frequently when trying to call objects in the frontend. I think this error occurs when the frontend loads before the information is called so here are my two workarounds.

To avoid this error I tried two things:

Firstly wrapping the element you're calling in an if statement in your frontend

```
{card != null ? 
    <>
      //show frontend
    </>
 : null }
```

Another good option would be just to use an activity indicator

The other thing I tried was creating another useEffect listener as follows:
const [called, setCalled] = useState(false);

Then once the data is fetched, I set this value to true. Then at the end of my useEffect I added called in the square brackets as a listener.

What this does is refreshes the frontend once that variable changes. I hope this kind of helps